# Rerunned test method marked as SKIPPED

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-eclipse

I wrote a script in selenium with TestNg framework such that the failed test method will be rerun, and this is at Test Level by indicating the location of the class that implements the `IRetryAnalyzer` in `@Test()`

TestNG had successfully rerun the failed test method; the output has the following information: for the first run, Failed Test Method is marked as Failed, and after rerunning it, the method is marked as skipped. What does it mean? Could anyone help me to interpret the result?

Here is the screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: how did you override methods of IRetryAnalyzer ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an ongoing issue on the official project.
You're welcome to follow:
https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/878